# EIP20.Sol does not compile. On remix.ethereum.org, I am trying to deploy a test token

Tags: solidity, remix, testnets, ethereum-classic

I followed the instructions and got an error:

> Parse Error Expected Token ; got 'LParen' emit Transfer(msg.sender,
>   _to_value);

How do I fix this?

Code:

```
function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) { 
    require(balances[msg.sender] >= _value); 
    balances[msg.sender] -= _value; 
    balances[_to] += _value; 
    emit Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value); //solhint-disable-line indent, no-unused-vars return true; 
}
```

Comment: From this video link   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d5EipPVafsA

Comment: The error is on line 43.  The code is below

Comment: function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        require(balances[msg.sender] >= _value);
        balances[msg.sender] -= _value;
        balances[_to] += _value;
        emit Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value); //solhint-disable-line indent, no-unused-vars
        return true; 
    }

Comment: The error is here        emit Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);

Comment: Please add your whole code to the question with proper formatting. I suspect you're using an old compiler version which does not yet support the `emit` keyword

Comment: It says too long by 2348 characters?

Comment: Well at least provide a link to the full code - you copypasted it from somewhere

Comment: pragma solidity ^0.4.21;

Comment: Here is the link to the code    https://github.com/ConsenSys/Tokens/blob/master/contracts/eip20/EIP20.sol

Answer (score 1):

If I copypaste the EIP20.sol and EIP20Interface.sol from the provided ConsenSys github to Remix (in the same file) it compiles just fine. Also I doubt ConsenSys would release code that doesn't even compile.

I suspect your problem is somewhere else. Maybe you accidentally modified your code somehow?

If you're saying that the error is in the `Transfer` line, then my guess is that your are using too old compiler which doesn't yet have the `emit` keyword for events. It's included in versions starting from 0.4.21.

Comment: Thanks for checking.  I am going to double check the code.  I am sure I did not touch anything except changing the 4.21 to 4.19 in EIP20Interface.sol because there was an error with 4.21?

Comment: In the link https://github.com/ConsenSys/Tokens/blob/master/contracts/eip20/EIP20Interface.sol

Comment: The code will not compile

Comment: pragma solidity ^0.4.21;

Comment: If you change it to 4.19 it will compile?

Comment: um. 0.4.19 will not compile because it does no have the `emit` keyword. You *have to* use 0.4.21 or newer.

Comment: Why then does the EIPInterface.sol not compile with version 4.21? Please advise hot to fix it.  Thanks.

Comment: It complies just fine here, as I already stated

Comment: Ok, I will try your suggestion.  Thank you for working with me.

Comment: I am having the same issue! The Interface file will only compile in 4.19 and the token file will not compile at all with these version. Having exact same parse error